# libGDX project setup, Mario

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, version, program-entry-point

New guy here, trying Java for the past 2 months. I came across a nice, in-depth tutorial by Brent Aureli on youtube. Seems like a really cool project! The tutorial is about creating Mario using libGDX, but already at the start of the project, I'm having problems.

**Error code 1:** `Could not determine java version from '9.0.1`'. Maybe something to do with the Java version as the tutorial is from August 2015?

**Error code 2:** `Class 'com.mygdx.mario.desktop.DesktopLauncher` not found in module 'PMario'. DesktopLauncher is, by the tutorial, supposed to be the main class. I can't seem to find it in Edit Config when trying to run the project.

This is all from his first video in the series (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8MPxzkwBwo&).

Heres a link to pictures of the setup and where it goes wrong:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLG2s.jpg
Link to better quality of picture 3 from album:
https://ibb.co/fQ5aWx

Anybody familiar with this error? Any tips welcome!!

Comment: We could debug it from your third pic, but there is too much jpg compression to read it.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) Sorry about that! Heres a better one: https://imgur.com/bQNSa0y

Comment: Still illegible. Can you post a PNG or is imgur downgrading your images?

Comment: Must be imgur that is downgrading. Uploaded to imgbb.com: https://ibb.co/fQ5aWx

Comment: Wohoo! Got Intellij to find the main file. From 2 errors to 1 :) Now, when it tries to run, the only error that shows up is "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'." Heres the screen now: https://ibb.co/ctLsTc

Answer (score 0):

Java version convention changed from '1.8' to '9.0', old gradle wrapper doesnt know what to do with that.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

3.3 should work, latest libgdx uses 4.6